# Creating new subclasses

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell and I have to create subclasses to use some functions from other existent Haskell classes, like the example below:

```
-- Create an example using the methods ceiling and floor from the class RealFrac
class (RealFrac f) => MeuFrac f where
    arredondaCima :: f -> f
    arredondaBaixo :: f -> f

    arredondaCima a = ceiling a
    arredondaBaixo a = floor a

arredondaBaixo a = floor a

instance MeuFrac RealFrac
```

But I've encountered this error:

```
• Expecting one more argument to ‘RealFrac’
  Expected a type, but ‘RealFrac’ has kind ‘* -> Constraint’
• In the first argument of ‘MeuFrac’, namely ‘RealFrac’
  In the instance declaration for ‘MeuFrac RealFrac’
```

and I can't manage to solve it.

Comment: The problem is `instance MeuFrac RealFrac`, since `RealFrac` is a typeclass, not a type.

Comment: Furthermore you define `arredondaBaixo` both in the typeclass and outside, which does not make much sense.

Comment: It is not entirelyclear however to me what you want to express. You say a subclass, but that means that not all `RealFrac` types are `MeuFrac`s, on the other hand with your `instance MeuFrac RealFrac`, it looks like you want to say that all `RealFrac`s are `MeuFrac`s.

Comment: Let me go out on a limb here and say that brand new Haskell programmers usually shouldn't write new classes at all. Spend a couple months writing functions, types, instances, and maybe even programs. Then circle around to classes once you have a better sense of what they're good for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 to @dfeuer's comment.  New Haskell programmers tend to overuse type classes because of their confusion about the relationship between Haskell type classes and "classes" in object-oriented languages.  This goes double for type *sub*classes.

In Java, if you want to "extend the functionality" of an existing class, the natural way to do this is to derive a subclass and define new methods.

In Haskell, if you want to "extend the functionality" of an existing type class, you almost always do this by writing top-level polymorphic functions that use the type class as a constraint.  For your specific example, if you want to extend the functionality of the `RealFrac` type class to allow any `RealFrac` to be rounded up and down, the right way to do it is to write the following at top-level:

```
roundUp :: (RealFrac a) => a -> a
roundUp x = fromIntegral (ceiling x :: Integer)

roundDown :: (RealFrac a) => a -> a
roundDown x = fromIntegral (floor x :: Integer)
```

As a technical note unrelated to the whole "type class" issue, observe that the `RealFrac a` constraint provides the facility to `ceiling` or `floor` a value of type `a` to any integral type, and the ability to `fromIntegral` any integral type back to type `a` (via the `Num` superclass).  A specific intermediate integral type must be picked for this transformation.  If you don't specify it explicitly, the compiler will choose a default (namely `Integer`).  I prefer to make this default explicit, which is why I've written `:: Integer`.

Comment: Thanks, @K. A !! I would love to have the time to learn more about haskell and practice it before trying classes and subclasses, but I needed that for a college stuff lmao thanks for your help, I understood better now how to deal with all that.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to convey that all `MeuFrac`s are automatically `RealFrac`s, then the way to do this is:

```
class MeuFrac f where
    -- ...

instance MeuFrac f => RealFrac f where
    -- here you must meet minimal instance definition for RealFrac
```

If, on the other hand, you want to say that all `MeuFrac`s must already be `RealFrac`s, then the syntax for that is:

```
class RealFrac f => MeuFrac f where
    -- here you can assume that f has a RealFrac instance

-- no instance declaration required
```

These two options are mutually exclusive. You can't create an `instance MeuFrac f => RealFrac f` if you have already required `RealFrac f => MeuFrac f` as a typeclass constraint. As Willem Van Onsem mentioned in comments, `instance MeuFrac RealFrac` is ill-formed because the syntax for instance declarations is `instance tc t`, where `tc` is a typeclass and `t` is a type; however, `RealFrac` is a typeclass and not a type.

Comment: Thanks, @Andrew, that clearified a lot to me!!